# Deleting polygons within larger polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, polygon-creation, delete

I'm using Google Earth Pro to create some maps. I have a larger area (polygon) that has a few smaller areas that are not legally considered part of that larger area. I created the larger area and then created a polygon for each area that needs to be removed. I imported all of them as one KML file into QGIS and also separately.

How do I get QGIS to remove these smaller polygons from the larger polygon? Kind of like a cookie cutter. Think of mapping the borders of Rome as one polygon, and then the Vatican City as another. You want to eliminate the Vatican City so that when you import it into GEP you've created a hole.

I've looked at some posts and videos of techniques that might work, however, either the command didn't work, or I can't access the command at all (e.g. Cut, Delete, etc.) I guess QGIS only presents allowed commands depending on what's going in in the layer. That's cool and all, but I can't figure out how to turn on the commands.

I've attached a pic of what I'm talking about. I need the three smaller polygons to cut holes in the larger one.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Use `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing Tools / Difference`.

*Blue Polygon minus yellow polygons = polygon outlined in red:*

[image]